# Installed Windows in wrong partition and now shows "no bootable device"

Tags: macos, mac, bootcamp

I chose the wrong partition to install Windows on my MacBook Pro Retina.

How do I reinstall Mountain Lion? I tried ⌘R but the only thing I get is:

> No Bootable Device -- Insert boot disk and press any key

Answer (score 1):

Since Boot Camp sets your Windows partition as the Startup Disk, some keyboard commands on boot become very temperamental or may not work at all.

Try holding <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd> on startup - see if you can select the recovery partition.

If not, you might have to re-install the OS from disc or external drive.